# Reference to concrete revision of entity

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have an entity with a reference to another entity, something like this:

```
@Entity(name = "MyCustomEntity")
@Table(name = "my_custom_entity")
public class MyCustomEntity {

    @Id
    Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
    OtherEntity other;
}
```

As it turns out, business logic dictates that `OtherEntity` should not be mutable in this context. Since you can still change the entity outside this context, I thought it was easiest to change the reference from `MyCustomEntity` to an Envers revision.

I could replace the reference with this snippet:

```
@Entity(name = "MyCustomEntity")
@Table(name = "my_custom_entity")
public class MyCustomEntity {

    @Id
    Integer id;

    Integer otherId;
    Integer revision;
}

OtherEntity getOther(MyCustomEntity entity) throws Exception {
   return auditReader.find(OtherEntity.class, entity.otherId, entity.revision);
}
```

But I'd lose a couple of Hibernate features that I'd rather have.

Is there a better way to reference an Envers revision?

Comment: So am i correct in that your primary goal is to make the relationship between `MyCustomEntity` and `OtherEntity` immutable so that once you've associated `OtherEntity#1234` to `MyCustomEntity#789` that it cannot be changed?

Comment: @Naros Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact you simply want to enforce immutability with the relationship between the two entities, why not simply make use of the `@Immutable` annotation here rather than trying to manipulate this through your model.

```
@Entity(name = "MyCustomEntity")
@Table(name = "my_custom_entity")
public class MyCustomEntity {
  @Id
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
  @Immutable
  private OtherEntity other;

  ...
}
```

But it's important to understand that `Immutable` in this content applies solely to ORM.

Lets say you perform the following actions

1. Create `MyCustomEntity`revision pointing to `OtherEntity`.
2. Modify `OtherEntity` (now has a higher revision number than `MyCustomEntity`)
3. Modify `MyCustomEntity` (now has a higher revision number than `OtherEntity`)
4. Query `MyCustomEntity` with latest revision.

That latest revision **will** point to the `OtherEntity` with modifications made in step 2.  The immutability annotation simply doesn't allow changing the FK reference.

Does that solve your issue?

**UPDATE**

> I want the `MyCustomEntity` to always point to the same version of `OtherEntity`. So even when `OtherEntity` changes, `MyCustomEntity` should not be able to see the changes.

That is precisely how Envers works.

The `MyCustomEntity` will only return the related association with a revision number that is equal-to or less-than its queried revision.

That means if you modify `OtherEntity` and then query `MyCustomEntity`, the returned instance of `OtherEntity` would not contain those recent changes.

The only time that `MyCustomEntity` would return the latest snapshot of the `OtherEntity` association would be if `MyCustomEntity` is modified in the same transaction or a future transaction after `OtherEntity`.

Associations are always returned with the associated entity-type having a revision number than is `<=` the queried entity's revision number.

> I'm changing both.

If you're changing both, then the order in which you perform those changes will play into what snapshot the relationship will return in audit queries.

If you're goal is to somehow **pin** a revision, there really isn't a good logical way to do that, at least not within the same transaction boundary anyway given how Envers performs its logic in a pre-commit transaction callback.

Comment: No, I seem to have misunderstood. I want the `MyCustomEntity` to always point to the same version of `OtherEntity`. So even when `OtherEntity` changes, `MyCustomEntity` should not be able to see the changes. The FK reference is inmutable, too, but that's not the main problem. Still thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you ever changing `MyCustomEntity` or only `OtherEntity`?  If only the latter, then `MyCustomEntity` would never see those changes anyway.

Comment: I'm changing both.